# How to get a Facebook page posts, and its comments in a single batch query via Graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, jsonpath

According to this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch, there's a way to use results of first query to populate second query.

```
curl \
   -F 'access_token=...' \
   -F 'batch=[{ "method": "GET", \
                "name" : "get-friends", \
                "relative_url": "me/friends?limit=5", \
              }, \
              { "method": "GET", \
                "relative_url": "?ids={result=get-friends:$.data.*.id}" \
              }]' \
      https://graph.facebook.com
```

However I want to get a page posts in first query and then get the individual posts' comments. Not sure if this is possible, any help is appreciated.

```
curl \
   -F 'access_token=...' \
   -F 'batch=[{ "method": "GET", \
                "name" : "get-posts", \
                "relative_url": "cocacola/posts?limit=5", \
              }, \
              { "method": "GET", \
                "relative_url": "?????" \
              }]' \
      https://graph.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily Facebook allows for multiple objects in a single query if you use `/comments?ids`

```
curl \
   -F 'access_token=...' \
   -F 'batch=[{ "method": "GET", \
                "name" : "get-posts", \
                "relative_url": "cocacola/posts?limit=5", \
              }, \
              { "method": "GET", \
                "relative_url": "/comments?ids={result=get-posts:$.data.*.id}" \
              }]' \
      https://graph.facebook.com
```

Unfortunately this is slower than doing 5 individual queries in parallel.